# Grails integration test mock not cleaned

Tags: grails

I've a strange polluting situation between two spock integration tests that I'm not able to resolve. I suppose that I'm doing something wrong but I can't understand what.

The two integration tests are testing different situation of the same controller. In the first one I mock a service while in the second I don't mock.

Here are the significant parts of two tests :

test 1:

```
// CodeControllerSpec.groovy
...
def controller = new CodeController()
def serviceMock = new MockFor(PollutingService)
serviceMock.demand.search(1) { a, b, c ->
    return [id: 1]
}
controller.myService.pollutingService = serviceMock.proxyInstance()
controller.save()
...
then: 
serviceMock.verify(controller.myService.pollutingService)
```

test 2:

```
// CodeEngineSpec.groovy
...
def controller = new CodeController()
controller.show()
...
then: 
...
```

Controller and services are as following

```
// CodeController
class CodeController extends RestfulController<Code> {
    def myService

    def show() {
        ...
        myService.execute()
        ...
    }
}

// MyService
class MyService {

    def pollutingService

    def execute() {
        ...
        pollutingService.search(a, b, c)
        ...
    }
}

// PollutingService
class PollutingService {

    def search(a, b, c) {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

If I run the two tests one by one, they all pass but, if I run them together, the second one fails with

`No more calls to 'search' expected at this point. End of demands.`

I'm sure that the mock in the first service is used (I've debugged code line by line) but I don't know why mock is not cleaned after test.
Any suggestion is really welcome.

I'm using grails 2.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using mocks in integration tests has unpredictable results.

But putting that aside, where is `controller.myService` in your first test being instantiated? I would have expected that calling `controller = new CodeController()` would bypass autowiring of `controller.myService`.

Comment: What do you mean with `using mocks in integration tests has unpredictable results.`? I was sure that service are autowired in integration tests, I'll give a try instantiating services

Comment: In any case, note that if `controller.myService` in the two tests are the same object, then `controller.myService.pollutingService` will also be the same object in the two tests.

Comment: In the next few days I'll write some new tests and verify your suggestions. In the meantime can you elaborate a bit the statement `using mocks in integration tests has unpredictable results.`? Thanks

Comment: More problematic than using mocks in integration tests is using unit test Mixins and annotations like @TestFor with integration tests, because of the mucking up of metaClasses they do behind the scenes. Mocks in integration tests is less problematic, but you have to keep track of what you're doing and clean up after yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the solution was to cleanup service(s) at the end of the integration test